# How to provide SSL for custom domains in a SaaS type product

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

I am curiuos if there is a way to provide custom domains served using SSL using the golang web server.

So there can be 1000's of custom domains that will have their DNS pointing to my golang based web server and I want the domains to be served using SSL.

Comment: There are many options. One of them is mentioned in your tags, so I'm not sure why you're asking. Beyond that, this question is too broad/off-topic as resource requests are off topic.